# Convert shell script to C# programming language

Tags: c#

can somebody please let me know me whether there is any possibility of converting shell scripts to C# programming language. I searched for a solution but failed.

Answer (score 4):

Not automatically. You need to understand what the script is doing and then write a C# program that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Language translation is possible, but converting a code to another, it is a simple job that a programmer can do itself. `Learn the logic and re-code`